# URL rewrite and GET parameter

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using htaccess url rewrite only for `index.php` and using PHP to capture the GET parameter. When trying different parameter my website is giving 404 error on certain parameter which I found very strange. However below are the details:

**htaccess**

`RewriteRule ^([^/index.php]*)$ /index.php?company=$1 [L]`

**index.php**

```
<?php
$name = 'specialpromo';

if(isset($_GET['company'])) {
    include 'include/dbconfig.php';  

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        $errmsg = "Connection error";
    } else {
        if(!(mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname))){
            $errmsg = "Database error";
        } else {
            $sql_comp = $conn->prepare("select a.* 
            from company a
            where a.code = ?");
            $sql_comp->bind_param('s', $_GET['company']);
            $sql_comp->execute();
            $rs_comp =  $sql_comp->get_result() or die('Error, query failed<br />');

            $numrow_comp = mysqli_num_rows($rs_comp);

            if ($numrow_comp==1){
                if($row_comp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_comp)){
                    $name = $row_comp['name'];
                }
            }

            mysqli_free_result($rs_comp);
        }
        mysqli_close ($conn);
    }
}
?>
```

Please try the URL below as both values are not in my database, they are giving weird result.

1. `https://shop.specialpromo.asia/ddd` will return error 404
2. `https://shop.specialpromo.asia/aaa` will load just fine although no result found

Comment: `[^/index.php]` is a character class, not an exclusion. It's reqivalent to `[^dehinpx./]` and covers `d…` obviously.

Comment: i see. How to make htaccess only allow rule for `index.php` then rewrite it?

Comment: Use a negative lookahead, or a RewriteCond to exclude index.php. The common RewriteCond !-f  approach might suffice even.

Comment: I only want the rewriterule to happen when the page is `index.php`, can you show me the code? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?company=$1 [L]
```

Line 1: if request uri does not match any existing directory

Line 2: if request uri does not match any existing file

Line 3: then for every request uri, rewrite to `index.php?company=$1`, `$1` is the backreference to the regex `(.*)`

Comment: cannot apply for all uri, must only apply to index.php itself. otherwise it would also rewrite for dashboard.php, product.php etc right?

Comment: it does not apply the `RewriteRule` if the request uri matches the existing file